# Create external customer from Devise user via HTTP request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api, devise

What I need is, immediately after a new user was created with Devise, my app to send an HTTP request (POST) with the ID of this user to an external API (which will create a Customer on that platform). The request will return a Customer_ID that needs to be stored in the database for the user.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`after_create` callback can come handy here.

In your User model,

```
after_create :set_customer_id

private

def set_customer_id
  response = API_REQUEST
  update_attribute(:customer_id, response.body[:customer_id])
end
```

Assuming, response body is `json` and required key is `customer_id`.

You can read about `before_create` and other callbacks [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) as pointed out in comments.

Comment: Hmm, this sounds like exactly what I need, gonna try it!

Comment: To piggyback, there's a lot of useful callbacks for keeping multiple services in sync: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html